# Traverse an Array so that the Number of Steps Taken on Each Element in the Array is Equal to its Place in the Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, traversal, graph-traversal

It was too hard to find decent and short title for this question.

Given N-size array with all elements are 0, when you step on an element, that element increments by one. Find the shortest path to sort array in ascending order from 0 to N-1. For example if N = 5, make the array from 0-0-0-0-0 to 0-1-2-3-4.

#### **Rules**

- If an element contains highest number (N-1), it will be lowest number(0) when you step on it.
- You have to start from the first element.
- You can only go next right or next left element.
- If you are on first element, you can only go right. If you are on last element, you can only go left.
- You can only step on one element at a time.

What is the best algorithm to find shortest path?

Answer (score 0):

A* is the answer.

```
add first element
adjacent returns the one/two adjacent elements, with their updated values and position.
A* it.
```

Adjacent just need to generate the next two values.
The heuristic is the sum distance to target.

Comment: How do you calculate distance when increment is wrapped by modulo?